# Problem wih 3D array making draw function that acts strange

Tags: java, processing

I wrote this code to check 3D arrays and how they work. I have a simple code that should first store values and then recall them in the draw part.
Instead of drawing the proper grids of dots, only 1 dot appears at about(110,5)

I have made sure that the program works, when I don't use the array to acces colors, but create them "on the spot". it works as expected then.

```
color [][][]array = new color[10][10][10];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void setup(){
  size(1100,1000);
  background(0);
  for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j= 0; i < 10; i++){
      for(int k= 0; i < 10; i++){
        array[1][j][k] = color(i*25.5,j*25.5,k*25.5);
      }
    }
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(0);
  stroke(0);
  for(int s= 0; s < 10; s++){
    x= 110*s;
    y= 110*s;
    for(int v= 0; v < 10; v++){
      for(int t= 0; t < 10; t++){
        fill(array[s][v][t]);
        ellipse(x+t*10+5,v*10+5,10,10);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `array[i][j][k]` instead of `array[1][j][k]` (focus on `i`) and `for(int j= 0; j < 10; j++)` insead of `for(int j= 0; i < 10; i++)` and `for(int k= 0; k < 10; k++)` instead of `for(int k= 0; i < 10; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you weren't incrementing the j/k on the triple for loop in the setup, here is the fixed code:

```
color [][][]array = new color[10][10][10];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void setup(){
  size(1100,1000);
  background(0);
  for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j= 0; j < 10; j++){
      for(int k= 0; k < 10; k++){
        array[1][j][k] = color(i*25.5,j*25.5,k*25.5);
      }
    }
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(0);
  stroke(0);
  for(int s= 0; s < 10; s++){
    x= 110*s;
    y= 110*s;
    for(int v= 0; v < 10; v++){
      for(int t= 0; t < 10; t++){
        fill(array[s][v][t]);
        ellipse(x+t*10+5,v*10+5,10,10);
      }
    }
  }

}
```